# PHP-Retrieve content from page

Tags: php, tags

I'd like to retrieve a page's content and reformat it to my liking...

For example:

- Go to example.com
- Get content within tags with class "x"
- Pass content to specific variables
- Spit out the content in some pretty form..array, csv, xml...

Not too hard, right?  I'm a PHP noob! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using [PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/).

You can do nice stuff like this:

```
// Create DOM from URL or file
$html = file_get_html('http://www.google.com/');

// Find all images
foreach($html->find('img') as $element)
       echo $element->src . '<br>';

// Find all links with class=x
foreach($html->find('a[class=x]') as $element)
       echo $element->href . '<br>';
```

Answer (score 1):

For getting the data, there are three levels of difficulty:

```
file_get_contents($url); //easy
```

Unfortunately a lot of sites aren't very responsive to the proper user agent. You've got two options, here. One's a little harder than the other. Intermediate is [Zend HTTP Client](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.http.html#zend.http.client.usage)

```
$client = Zend_Http_Client(); //make sure to include Zend_Http, etc.
$client->setConfig($params); // params will include proper user agent
$client->setUri($aUrl);
$html = $client->request()->getBody();
```

Option three, which you might not even want to consider unless you really want to keep it more scripting than object-oriented, is to explore PHP's [cURL functionality](https://www.php.net/curl)

There are a few PHP-native ways to access HTML data via a DOM object, but my favorite is the [Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/).  It's very similar to jQuery/CSS style DOM navigation.

```
$domObject = new Simple_HTML_Dom($html);
foreach ($domobject->find('div#theDataYouWant p') as $sentence)
{
    echo "<h3>{$sentence}</h3>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

XSD might do the trick for you. I'd also consider wget + CSS...