# PHP-Retrieve specific content from multiple pages of a website

Tags: php, dom

What I want to accomplish might be a little hardcore, but I want to know if it's possible:

**The question:**
My question is the same as [PHP-Retrieve content from page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144394/php-retrieve-content-from-page), but I want to use it on multiple pages.

**The situation:**
I'm using a website about TV shows. All the TV shows have the same URL and then the name of the show:
http://bierdopje.com/shows/NAME_OF_SHOW
On every show page, there's a line which tells you if the show is cancelled or still running. I want to retrieve that line to make an overview of the cancelled shows (the website only supports an overview of running shows, so I want to make an extra functionality).

**The real question:**
How can I tell DOM to retrieve all the shows and check for the status of the show?
(http://bierdopje.com/shows/*).

**The Note:**
I understand that this process may take a while because it is reading the whole website (or is it too much data?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use [phpquery](http://code.google.com/p/phpquery/) to fetch data from a web page, like jQuery in Dom.

For example, to get the list of all shows, you can do this :

```
<?php
require_once 'phpQuery/phpQuery/phpQuery.php';

$doc = phpQuery::newDocumentHTML(
    file_get_contents('http://www.bierdopje.com/shows')
);

foreach (pq('.listing a') as $key => $a) {

    $url = pq($a)->attr('href'); // will give "/shows/07-ghost"
    $show = pq($a)->text(); // will give "07 Ghost"

}
```

Now you can process all shows individualy, make a new phpQuery::newDocumentHTML for each show and with an selector extract the information you need.

---

Get the status of a show

```
$html = file_get_contents('http://www.bierdopje.com/shows/alcatraz');
$doc = phpQuery::newDocumentHTML($html);

$status = pq('.content>span:nth-child(6)')->text();
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. This worked just fine.
This is not entirely what I mean, though. I want every single show on the site to be checked (not the overview). You say I can make a new phpQuery::newDocumentHTML, but that would take too much work, since there are thousands of shows. Isn't there a way to check every show (new URL per show)?

Comment: my sample script can help you to get the list of every show you need. You can store the result into a table(all urls). Sorry, To check every show, you need the fetch the html code of every show first, then with pq(selector) you can check the status one show after another.

Comment: It's not about the shows on the page bierdopje.com/shows, but shows which arent listed, like [link](http://www.bierdopje.com/shows/alcatraz)Alcatraz[/link]. Do you know how I can find them, get the urls and then after check the status with your script?

Comment: I added a sample to show you how to get the status of a show. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

use this code to fetch only the links from the single website.

```
include_once('simple_html_dom.php');

$html = file_get_html('http://www.couponrani.com/');

// Find all links
foreach($html->find('a') as $element) 
       echo $element->href . '<br>';
```

Comment: You forget to mention link and details for PHP class `simple_html_dom.php` Hope you will update your answer.